# Can we use listview for heterogeneous collections

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-scrollview

I need to create a feed screen like facebook application where I will fetch data from api and each row has different size of images and text.
I know ScrollView is for both homogeneous and heterogeneous collection and listView is for only homogeneous collection but can I use listview for heterogeneous collections for feed. ?

Comment: have you tried custom adapter?

Comment: Well i am using react native and custom adapter does not exist in react-native. my question is that is it possible? if it is then react-native definitely support for this.

Comment: @SamratDas it is possible by using listview.

Comment: It's almost like a top google hit. Word for word.  https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Implementing-a-Heterogenous-ListView

Comment: @waleedarshadmuhammadarshad you can easily do this with recyclerView with different type https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. React native handle is very efficiently. i have left no option except to implement and see if it works and yes it is working awesomely. 
Also this post help me a lots to go through [Recycling Rows For High Performance React Native List Views](https://medium.com/@talkol/recycling-rows-for-high-performance-react-native-list-views-628fd0363861#.ac8osmd08)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
private List mList = new ArrayList();

mList.add("String");
mList.add('A');
mList.add(true);

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ......
    ......
    ......
    if(mList.get(position) instanceof String){

    }else if(mList.get(position) instanceof Character){

    }else if(mList.get(position) instanceof Boolean){

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(mList.get(position) instanceof String){
        return 0;
    }else if(mList.get(position) instanceof Character){
        return 1;
    }else if(mList.get(position) instanceof Boolean){
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or normalize them into a common Class.